# How is it possible to ionize air with wavelengths longer than the UV dictated by the ionization potential?

Tags: optics, atomic-physics, laser, non-linear-optics, ionization-energy

I understand that molecular oxygen has an ionization potential of around 13.6 eV and molecular nitrogen sits at around 14.8 eV; these correspond to wavelengths of around 80 nm and 92 nm, respectively, via $\lambda=hc/I_p$ for $hc=1240\mathrm{\:nm\:eV}$.

My question is how do people manage to ionize with light of much longer wavelengths ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b--lWjALFvQ), [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1Xky_ermd4), [example](https://laserpointerforums.com/f54/question-about-laser-can-ionize-air-93208.html)) if the photon energy for that light is so low? Or are my numbers for the ionization potential of air molecules wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a citation to support your claim that these molecules can be ionised with long wavelength lasers? Incidentally NIST give the ionisation energies of the oxygen and nitrogen molecules as $12.07$ and $15.58$eV respectively.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b--lWjALFvQ and 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1Xky_ermd4
And there are a few posts about it on the laserpointerforum https://laserpointerforums.com/f54/question-about-laser-can-ionize-air-93208.html
. in both examples they are using a q-switched ND:YAG laser which is 1064nm and thank you for the clarificaion on ev for air molecules.

Comment: There are many more that i have found and will add onto the post as i find more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conversions are correct - if you want to ionize air molecules with a single photon, then you'll need photons with wavelength shorter than 80nm or so.

However, for the videos you give as examples, that's not the physical mechanism at play. Optical breakdown in air, as in general dielectrics, is an avalanche process. In this process you start with a seed electron, which gets accelerated by the laser field to higher and higher energies until it hits a neutral molecule and, via collisional ionization, knocks out a second electron. You now have two electrons, which get accelerated and hit other molecules, knocking out even more free charge, in an exponential process, which quickly develops into an ionized plasma that can absorb radiation directly, heating up in the process. The emitted light comes from the plasma; the sound comes from its expansion in air and the subsequent collapse of the evacuated bubble it generates.

Now, to have that avalanche process, you need to get that seed electron from somewhere, and here [the dynamics change depending on the pulse duration](https://www.rp-photonics.com/laser_induced_breakdown.html): the seed electrons normally come from a mixture of free electrons naturally present in air (though see also [doi](https://doi.org/10.1109/JQE.1969.1075758) / [eprint](https://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/04/083/4083781.pdf)), and electrons ionized via multiphoton ionization, with the relative importance of multiphoton ionization increasing for shorter pulses that get closer to the femtosecond regime.

---

Now, even if you take the avalanche process out of the equation, a laser with photon energy that's smaller than the ionization potential can still, if it is intense enough, produce ionization via two-photon processes (or higher). This dates all the way back to 1965 [[reference](http://jetpletters.ru/ps/1590/article_24398.shtml), [reference](http://www.jetp.ras.ru/cgi-bin/e/index/r/50/1/p78?a=list)] ─ you do need a laser to get the required intensities, but once lasers were invented it took only five years for experiments to show clear indications of *six*-photon ionization experiments.

Now, the higher the number of photons you need to ionize, the higher the required intensity, so if you want to meaningfully ionize air with laser light in the 1µm range then you're looking at a ~12-photon process, which explains the need for Q-switched pulsed lasers at the very least. In addition to that, the high photon count of the process means that it is highly nonlinear (though still a leading-order perturbative process unlike, say, [HHG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_harmonic_generation)), i.e. the probability of an $n$-photon process scales as $\mathrm{intensity}^n$, and that explains why the optical breakdown is strongly localized to the optical focus instead of slowly ramping up as the intensity increases.

Also, depending on conditions, if the laser is intense enough then the induced third-order nonlinearity in air can cause an effect called [Kerr self-focusing](https://www.rp-photonics.com/self_focusing.html), which is a runaway positive feedback loop where an intense laser induces a "virtual lens" in the air through nonlinear processes, causing it to focus into a tighter beam with a higher intensity, and so on and on until you reach the threshold for optical breakdown. That then means that you don't need such crazy-intense lasers, or particularly clean focusing conditions, to reach those intensity regimes. (For more on what can happen after the breakdown, see [laser filamentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filament_propagation).)

And also, if a twelve-photon process sounds crazy, then consider e.g. [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.79.033842), with ~150-photon processes, or [this one](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/336/6086/1287.short), with processes of order 5000 and higher.

Comment: hey emilio, I asked a new question about the photon process to try to get more details, and someone said that is was a duplicate of this question. I know you have helped and seen many posts on this forum and you were very helpful before. can you tell me if i should remove the question of maybe can you help me answer it. my goal by asking these questions is to 1 help me and 2 help other people who are confused on the same topics. please consider, thank you.

Comment: @ReeseHouseknecht BTW, this answer is probably only an incomplete description of the process but I'm still puzzling out exactly what does go on in optical breakdown as in your examples. My impression is that multiphoton ionization is probably the kick-off of the process, but once there are a few electrons around, the plasma formation is probably driven by laser acceleration of the free electrons followed by collisional ionization in an avalanche process. An update to this answer is coming, stay tuned.

Comment: looking forward to it, any new information helps me out.

Comment: @ReeseHouseknecht See edited answer.

Comment: So wait, in a previous post you said that pulse duration doesnt matter, which made perfect sense. but on that website you linked this is what he said, "The intensity required for optical breakdown depends on the pulse duration. For example, for 1-ps pulses an optical intensity of ≈ 2 × 1013 W/cm2 is required for breakdown in air at normal pressure."

Comment: Yes. That's because the dielectric breakdown itself, once you have your seed electrons, is an avalanche process, which brings in a huge number of additional variables. If you want to understand it in any more detail then it will very quickly become extremely complicated physics.

Comment: i thank you alot emilio so i have a question (about posting questions ironically) I'm obviously still confused and i want to help out people trying to do this just like you are helping me know, so i a want to post another question to the community about pulsing for ionization, because if someone needs that info its out there rather then me continue to question you in this different topic question. do you think this is wise or no, i just want to help the community and myself and i think i should do it but i figured in would ask:)

Comment: Don't ask with a future audience in mind - just ask what you want to know and let future users sort themselves out. And stop beating around the bush, just ask about what you actually want to do instead of asking lots of semi-related questions that touch on what you want but don't resolve it.

Comment: thanks emilio. i only post so little at a time because as a question is answered i immediately find a new question that confuses the hell out of me so i'm sorry for that, ill try to minimize the topics being related.