# Increasing wavelength for same electronvolts output using multiphoton process

Tags: laser

It is clear that in a multiphoton process the pulse duration is what matters, determining how many photons are in a pulse is how you can calculate the ev output. I made up a chart that is 100% wrong but maybe you will all see how I'm going about this

> ## Photoionizing N2 (15.58eV)
>
> ### Wavelength      Pulse rate
>
> 80nm                             virtually nothing because there is always 1 photon
>   200nm                          100 picoseconds
>   500nm                          10 picoseconds
>   800nm                          1 picosecond
>   980nm                          50 femtoseconds
>   1064nm                        10 femtoseconds

Now I know this is 100% wrong but maybe you can help me by seeing how I'm going about this, in each column as the wavelength increases so do the pulses so you can still output the same eV.

Comment: You give the wavelength and the Pulse rate but not the intensity. For instance a 500 nm photon has a frequency of about 600 trillion Cycles per second. It wouldn’t matter what the pulse rate was, you still just have one photon. The intensity would increase with more photons but you don’t give that information.

Comment: OHHH, so pulsing it doesnt mean jack for how many photons but the Joules i presume is how you determine how many photons are in a pulse? is this correct

Comment: so this you mean like if i had 500J that would increase the number of photons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, **multiphoton processes do not change the photon energy of the light** (which is what you incorrectly call "the eV of the light"). Multiphoton processes simply use multiple photons to enable processes that require higher energies than are available with a single photon.

In addition, while the pulse duration is a *relevant* quantity to the probability of multiphoton processes, it is not a *determining* quantity. What matters is the intensity (or, equivalently, the photon flux density, i.e. the number of photons passing per unit transverse area per unit time). If you don't know the pulse energy and the focal-spot waist, the pulse duration is useless in finding it.

And, as mentioned in [a previous answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/365993/8563), if what you want is to observe the sparks and pops of optical breakdown in air, the *seed* of the process might be multiphoton ionization, but the *bulk* of the ionization and plasma creation is via collisional ionization in an avalanche process where ionized electrons hit other molecules and knock other electrons out. (Just to be explicit about this: this is *not* what's normally understood by a multiphoton process.) As with multiphoton ionization, the pulse duration is *relevant* but it is not the only quantity of interest.

---

And as for this,

> help me by seeing how I'm going about this

we can't help until you say what "this" is and what you actually want to achieve. If all you want is to see pretty sparks then *just come out and say so* straight-up, instead of continuously beating around the bush with questions that don't actually address what you really want to know.

Comment: emilio i know this all makes sense to you but im very confused on how this works, and im sure most people are that are coming to this question and have the same problems. im beating around the bush because i never know what my next question is until the previous is answered and a new one arrises

Comment: yes i do want to make "pretty sparks" but its not that i just want that, i want to understand how and why, and if we can do it better, thats why im asking alot of questions

Answer (score 0):

I think i have finally made my mind click to hiw this process works, if my answer is wrong just tell me. So as emilio was saying you cant increase the ev of a laser by pulsing it, but each photon has its own "eV" (i quote it because i dont know if im using ev the right way) so in a 80nm laser each photons "ev" is 15.58 so it could photo ionize nitrogen. Now in a 980 nm wave each photon is 1.27ev you need ~12 photons to slam into the atom at such a fast rate that it basically gets hit with 15.58 ev. The onlything i still didnt figure out is pulse rate but is my take on the multiphoton process correct?

UPDATE: This is another guess but in each pulse i think there is only one photon, but if you pulse in femtoseconds, the laser will hit the atom so quick that the photon add up and ionize, if this is wrong please tell me