# How do people Ionize with higher watt lasers?

Tags: photons, laser, ionization-energy

A double covalent bond of nitrogen ($\mathrm{N}_2$) has an ionization potential of 15.58eV. Now lets go into an example. If I have a laser of wavelength $\lambda = 477\:\mathrm{nm}$ and I calculate the photon energy as $E = 1240\:\rm{eV\: nm}/\lambda$ then I get $2.6\:\mathrm{eV}$ per photon.

Now if I do $15.58\:\mathrm{eV}/2.6\:\mathrm{eV}$ it equals ${\sim}6$ photons.

Now, to figure out what pulse energy is required for 1 photon I do
$$
E
=\frac{hc}{\lambda} 
= \frac{6.626\times 10^{-34}\:\mathrm{J\: s} \times 3\times 10^{17}\:\mathrm{nm/s}}{477\:\mathrm{nm}}
\approx 4.167\times 10^{-19}\:\mathrm J,
$$
and for 6 photons that's $2.500\times 10^{-18}\:\mathrm J$.

Now if I want to get 6 photons in a pulse then I would need a pulse energy of $2.500\times 10^{-18}\:\mathrm J$, right? All I want to know is why does it require such low amounts of energy to do this, when all I see is that you need *a lot* of watts to ionize. Now as I was typing this I thought that maybe that equation shows how many joules of energy are in each photon, but yet [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=era8_50cKyA) says "Joules required per photon". But if this equation is not right then what equation should I use?

Comment: Perhaps you should step back a bit and dig into what is happening physically in multi-photon ionization. Basically, you need <a lot of photons> in a short time to have <the 6 you need> happen to be there at pretty much the exact same time. All the others? Well, the timing just wasn't right.

Comment: But how do I calculate how i would only get 6 to hit because anymore then 6 will not ionize. Is this why ultrafast pulses are needed?

Comment: Yes, basically you need the ultrafast pulses so that the 6 needed photons all happen by at the right time.

Comment: So i saw an equation W/Hz = Joules per 1 nano second pulse, but for watts i convert my 4.167e-19 joules but i just dont know if that number is right, it seems awfully small dont u think

Comment: even using femtosecond laser, people still use extremly high amounts of watts, which still wouldnt make sense?

Comment: Remember that Watts is energy per unit time. It doesn't take much total energy in a femtosecond laser pulse to get to many many Watts.

Comment: Do they even make lasers that can pulse and have a wattage of 4.167e-19 in each pulse? How would you even get something so specific

Comment: You continue to mix up Joules vs Watts.

Comment: ohh crap, i messed a few things up. so 1W = 1 joule per second. I have 2.5002e-18 J per nanosecond (this is for 6 photons) so i did 2.5002e-18 X 1,000,000,000W / 1J per ns to get 2.5002e-9W. this is still really small, but not as small as e-18

Comment: and if i did the same thing where it was 2.5002e-18 J per femtosecond then it would require 0.0025002 watts per pulse, which is now becoming more reasonable.

Comment: but i still wonder why people need so many watts to complete the process, or how it even works with such high wattage

Comment: I am going to do one more formatting edit to showcase some language you consistently use incorrectly (in particular, conflating quantities with their units), and which consistently degrade the quality of your questions, as an indication of things to improve in future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't much more to say that isn't well summed up by Jon Custer's initial comment,

> Perhaps you should step back a bit and dig into what is happening physically in multi-photon ionization. Basically, you need  in a short time to have  happen to be there at pretty much the exact same time. All the others? Well, the timing just wasn't right.

In quantum mechanics, the [totalitarian principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle) tells you, basically, that if something *can* happen, it *must* happen. However, it doesn't tell you *how often* it will happen.

For the multiphoton ionization you're asking about, your calculations show that there is a six-photon ionization process that's possible for the nitrogen molecule subjected to a 477nm laser. However, what you *don't* learn from that calculation is how likely that process is to happen: if your laser is weak, you're likely to have one or two electrons get ionized on occasion; that might be once per million ages of the universe, but it's still a positive rate so the process is happening.

To get the pretty sparks of laser-induced optical breakdown in air, however, you don't just need a nonzero rate, you need enough electrons to kick-start the avalanche process of dielectric breakdown. That is, you need the ionization rate be macroscopically meaningful, not just nonzero.

So, what is this ionization rate, and how does one calculate it? Well, it calls on a completely different set of concepts than just the photon-energy layer that you've used to compute whether the processes are possible. More specifically, what you want is the multiphoton ionization *cross section*, which depends critically on the *intensity* of the laser (that is, the concentration of the laser energy, not just the total energy of the pulse).

I won't go hunting on a wild-goose chase of moving goalposts for the specific parameters you've posted, but I'll start you off with [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.25.1483), which measures the cross-section of $(9\pm1)$-photon ionization of molecular nitrogen under the influence of a $1.06\:\mu\rm m$ neodymium-glass laser. (Note that ionizing from the ground state at this wavelength would take some 14 photons; here there's probably nontrivial additional physics going on.) Generally, the ionization probability through an $n$-photon process scales (by definition of the latter) as
$$
\mathrm{ionization\ rate} =\mathrm{constant}\times\mathrm{intensity}^n,
$$
i.e., as the $n^\rm{th}$ power of the intensity. This scaling is extremely important, but you still require at least one data point to fix that constant, and this is pegged by the single measurement that at intensity $I_0=2.44\times10^{12}\:\rm{W/cm^2}$ the ionization rate is about $r(I_0)=3\times 10^6/\rm s$, i.e. about three million per second. (It's important to note that these numbers are not transferable, and they do not apply to other molecular species or other driver wavelengths. If you want numbers for other configurations, do your own literature search, like everyone else.) That data point allows us to estimate the ionization rate at arbitrary intensities $I,$ as
$$
r(I) = \left(\frac{I}{2.44\times10^{12}\:\rm{W/cm^2}}\right)^9\times 3\times 10^6/\rm s.
$$

This is why you need high-power lasers: because if the intensity is, say, a factor of ten smaller than the reference intensity, at $I=2.44\times10^{11} \:\rm{W/cm^2}$, then the ionization rate will drop *by nine orders of magnitude*. That's a billion times. There's other factors involved, but when you have a multiphoton process with this kind of scaling, that stuff-to-the-ninth-power dependence trumps most everything else.

Since you do seem to need some help with the actual numbers, let me plug in a few for you. Suppose that we take the pulse energy $E$ as in your question, i.e. just nine photons in the pulse, with pulse energy $E=9h\nu = 10.5 \:\mathrm{eV} = 1.7\times 10^{-18}\:\rm J$, and let's use pulse of one-picosecond duration $\tau$ with beam waist $w$ of a hundred microns. Then the peak intensity is roughly
$$
I=\frac{E}{\pi w^2\tau}=53\:\rm{W/cm^2},
$$
and we expect it to produce, on average,
$$
r(I)\times\tau = \tau\times\left(\frac{E/\pi w^2\tau}{2.44\times10^{12}\:\rm{W/cm^2}}\right)^9\times 3\times 10^6/\rm s \approx 10^{-132}
$$
electrons per atom per shot - i.e. nothing anywhere near remotely measurable. On the other hand, if we put in something more macroscopically meaningful as our pulse energy - say, a per-pulse energy of $E=1\:\rm mJ$, corresponding to one watt of average power at a 1kHz repetition rate, then that increases to about $10^{-5}$ electrons per atom per shot, on average; when you add in the number of atoms in your focal volume, that can give you enough electrons to seed the avalanche process. But once you start playing with those numbers, it will hopefully become obvious just how crucial is the dependence on both the beam waist, the pulse energy, and the pulse duration.

To put things a bit more informally, the $n^\rm{th}$-power dependence is exactly what you would expect if the process required the photons to be present not just in the pulse somewhere, but directly on the molecule all at the same time. (That's not the actual origin, but the analogy is useful.) You can't just say "my pulse has nine photons, I can ionize one electron" - you need all those photons to lie on top of each other both temporally (thus requiring a short pulse, and changing the dependence from pulse energy to the peak power, a.k.a. energy flow rate) and spatially across the transverse directions of the pulse (thus requiring a tight focus, and changing the dependence from power to intensity (more precisely, [irradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance)) and adding the $/\rm{cm}^2$ to the units of the quantity of interest).

Comment: Emilio, i thank you immensely. I know you think these questions are dumb i truly know nothing and everything you say helps he alot. I dont know why you thumbs down my question as there are more people then i who want to know jt.

Comment: I consistently downvote your questions because I consistently think that they are poorly phrased, with poor previous research, asking about the wrong aspects of the subject, and not useful for future visitors. (And, moreover, you continue to make elementary mistakes after having them pointed out to you multiple times, which doesn't help at all.) That doesn't mean I'll stop answering them and helping you when I am able, but the post score is a valuable indicator of usefulness for future visitors and I'll continue to make objective use of it.

Comment: I will work on my question asking, I appreciate your honesty

Comment: ok emilio, if i had 0.25W/1Hz = 0.25J. now if i pulsed that at 150ns then i do (250mW)/150e-9) = 1,666,666,666Watts at peak intensity. i found this at <http://www.sal.wisc.edu/~khn/salt/Outgoing/Laser_Cutter/Tech%20note%20for%20pulsed%20beam%20characterization.pdf> but if the intensity is so high why would the wavelength matter anymore, because 1000 of photons will hit the electron all at the same time with 1,666,666,66 watts